# Use of microsoft sharepoint foundation subscription settings service?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

What is the exact use of microsoft sharepoint foundation subscription settings service in SharePoint App Model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This service supports site subscriptions. It has some characteristics in common with IIS Web Services as it is a WCF Web service and the object that represents it at runtime is an [SPIisWebService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spiiswebservice(v=office.14).aspx)-derived object. However, it does not implement the [Service Application Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee536263(v=office.14).aspx).

In SharePoint 2010, SharePoint uses this service application for Multi-tenant Mode or sites that use site subscriptions. In a multi-tenant environment, this service application stores the subscriptions settings and configuration data.

In SharePoint 2013, the introduction of App Management Service Application and Subscription Settings Service Application is one of the prerequisites of it. The App Management Service is inherently subscription aware and does NOT need to be provisioned in Partitioned Mode.

Same case with SharePoint 2016.

Apps rely on the App Management and Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings service applications. **These service applications use the multi-tenancy features to provide app permissions and create the subdomains for apps**.

**Known Facts:**

- There is no GUI to provision this Service Application
- Provisioned via PowerShell only
- This Service Application has it's own Content Database

**Reference:**

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33967.sharepoint-2016-subscription-settings-service-application-step-by-step.aspx
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx

Comment: "Down voters": Please do comments for down voting in order to identify mistakes in answer.